# Will ASP.NET HttpHandler trigger Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net

I suspect if I put following in abc.aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="imgVerify" Width="60" Height="18" runat="server" align="absmiddle" Style="border: 1px solid #999999" ImageUrl="/Common/GetCaptcha.aspx" />
```

It'll also trigger Page_Load() of abc.aspx.

Is this that true? And if it is, can I avoid it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your ASPX page will live its full lifecycle. If you want to serve images and whatnot, resort to plain `IHttpHandler`s.

Comment: Very clean, simple and perfect answer!